# DataGridViewColumnHeader Make Bold

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have one `DataGridView` and want to make the Header text Bold.
I have tried changing the `ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle` to
`DataGridViewCellStyle { BackColor=Color [Control], SelectionBackColor=Color [Highlight], SelectionForeColor=Color [HighlightText], Font=[Font: Name=Tahoma, Size=9.75, Units=3, GdiCharSet=0, GdiVerticalFont=False], WrapMode=True, Alignment=MiddleCenter }`

In the designer I can see the Headers as Bold but at runtime it shows as normal.
Please not that apart from `ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle` I am also changing 
`DefaultCellStyle` of `DataGridView` as well as of Individual Columns.

How to make the headers bold ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Suppose you want to change the style of column `0` of DataGridView `myDataGrid`:

```
myDataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, FontStyle.Bold);
```

If you want to change the default for headers:

```
myDataGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, FontStyle.Bold);
```

**EDIT:**

In the designer you can click on the properties box of the control, click on the small box beside `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle` property, expand `Font` and set `Bold=True`: [image]

Comment: Thanks but how can I change it in the designer ?

Comment: Alex, Please see my question, I had already tried that and it shows as bold in design time, but when in run time it's not bold. I guess it is because I am setting other properties also. See my question. Maybe it gets overridden by other properties ?

Comment: I reckon it does. Because I tried my answer from my machine and it worked. I have not changed any other properties though.

Comment: I had the Font of the Form set and maybe due to ambient property concept it made the header of DataGridView show as non-bold.

Comment: Yeah, that overwrites whatever you set in designer.

Comment: Is it possible to change only some of the words? I need this functionality to show highlights. So, not showing the whole row in bold, but just some of the words.

Comment: From the Designer page, as you requested:
`dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;`

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(DataGridView.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my answer--only you are two years late.

Comment: I find this more useful since there is no need to figure out the font name and attributes and also for setting the default values so that we don't have to set each column individually.

Answer (score 1):

This is with respect to the @Shaahin comment.

Here put `dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font`
instead of `DataGridView.DefaultFont`
Here we are re-assigning the font to the `datagridview` so we have to apply the font same `datagridview`'s font not `DataGridView.DefaultFont`.
In working conditions `DataGridView.DefaultFont` and `dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font` may have different values

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

The above code is converted from a VB.Net to C#.Net by some tool. Please don't go for syntax rather concept.